# What is the easiest way to clone a webservice?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, web-services, clone

I'm working on a project where we will be connecting to a Oracle webservice using .NET (c#). The only thing is that we will build our client from our office location, but our  customer will not give us remote access to their web service (company policy, etc). So our solution was to visit our customer on-site and 'clone' their webservice so that we can use the surrogate webservice to develop our client against.

What would be the best way to clone this webservice?

Our clone will need to output sample data, but use their exact method calls and types. Our preferred language to do the clone in is c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get a hold of the WSDL and any associated XSDs and use WSDL.exe to generate the classes and add them to a webservice project.

Answer (score 1):

*"Our clone will need to output sample data, but use their exact method calls and types."*

So it's maybe enough to record the original webservice data and play it back?

As startpoint, [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) with *Autoresponse* may help. As advanced solution your partner is [SOAPUI](http://www.soapui.org/features.html#Web_Service_Simulation).

[image]
<sub>(source: [soapui.org](http://www.soapui.org/images/screenshot5.gif))</sub>